How to download an image file using the Google Drive API in a Lambda Function in Python?
I'm trying to download an image file (in a raw .cr2 format, but could change if needed) from Google Drive to AWS Lambda so I can edit using Pillow and upload the edited image back to drive.
I've tried two approaches to download the image following this documentation.

Get
Export

When I use Get, with the code below:
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(filename=SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)

fh = io.BytesIO()
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
done = False
while done is False:
    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
    print("Download %d%%" % int(status.progress() * 100))

I get the following error:
{
"errorMessage": "<HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/XXXXX?alt=media returned \"Only files with binary content can be downloaded. Use Export with Docs Editors files.\". Details: \"[{'message': 'Only files with binary content can be downloaded. Use Export with Docs Editors files.', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'fileNotDownloadable', 'location': 'alt', 'locationType': 'parameter'}]\">",
  "errorType": "HttpError",
  "requestId": "XXXXX",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 44, in lambda_handler\n    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py\", line 130, in positional_wrapper\n    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py\", line 780, in next_chunk\n    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self._uri)\n"
  ]
}

When I try the Export method:
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(filename=SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)


request = drive_service.files().export_media(fileId=file_id, mimeType=file_type)

fh = io.BytesIO()
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
done = False
while done is False:
    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
    print("Download %d%%" % int(status.progress() * 100))

the error is:
{
"errorMessage": "<HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/XXXXX/export?mimeType=image%2Fjpeg&alt=media returned \"Export only supports Docs Editors files.\". Details: \"[{'message': 'Export only supports Docs Editors files.', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'fileNotExportable'}]\">",
  "errorType": "HttpError",
  "requestId": "XXXXX",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 47, in lambda_handler\n    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py\", line 130, in positional_wrapper\n    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py\", line 780, in next_chunk\n    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self._uri)\n"
  ]
}

Was it the correct way to download an image from drive using a Lambda function in Python?

Use file.get instead

About both scripts in your question, did you use the same value of file_id?

@Tanaike used both with same IDs, and also tried different IDs.

Thank you for replying. About both with same IDs, in this case, one of export_media and get_media can be used. But, in your question, it seems that an error occurs for the same file ID with both export_media and get_media. In this case, it is required to know the method for correctly replicating your situation. So, can you provide the detailed information for correctly replicating it? By this, I would like to confirm it.
